# Should I allow packages to be downgraded by synaptic?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

On synaptic, I want to install dkpg-dev, but synaptic need to downgrade libdkpg-perl for this. Is it a good idea to allow that or I will run into broken packages issues. What rule of thumb do you use in this cases ? I have a newly installed Ubuntu 14.04. How come I run into this ? Thank you.
.

.

-------------------------------- EDIT 1

Here is my sources.list:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the    Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the    Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

and my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ is empty

.
-------------------------------- EDIT 2

Actually, I re-installed libdkpg-perl. It was

"installed version: 1.17.5ubuntu5.3 and latest: 1.17.5ubuntu5"

I am not sure how I get to this. Is it due to my sources.list ?

After I re-installed, I have:

"installed version: 1.17.5ubuntu5 and latest: 1.17.5ubuntu5"

It is equivalent to a downgrade

.

Comment: Try running `apt-get update` and then `apt-get upgrade`. I think you may be trying to install an outdated version of `dpkg-dev`.

Comment: I don't want to upgrade though

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` only updates your packages; it doesn't upgrade your Ubuntu installation. `apt-get dist-upgrade` will upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the following commands in a terminal, in order to update the package sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run the installation of `dkpg-dev` again:

```
sudo apt-get install dkpg-dev
```

Based on your `sources.list` and an empty `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, accepting the downgrade should pose no problem.

Comment: When I do the update and go back to synaptic, I have the same behaviour as before

Comment: @BobYoplait After update and install?

Comment: after update, I go to synaptic to try to instal again dkpg-dev, and it still ask me for downgrade of   libdkpg-perl. If I do it from the command line, I get:"libdpkg-perl (= 1.17.5ubuntu5) but 1.17.5ubuntu5.3 is to be installed"

Comment: @BobYoplait Which package sources do you use?

Comment: @AB I added my sources.list in the EDIT

Comment: @BobYoplait accept the downgrade 

Answer (score 1):

You may allow it, that's not a problem. The packages synaptic offers are the dependencies of the packages you want to install.